# Строка "Итого" в таблице (JS)

Tags: javascript, html5

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста реализовать механизм, который при условии наличия строк в таблице будет добавлять в конце строку с общей суммой по колонке `Price`? Спасибо!

```js
function insertRow(id) {
  var tbody = document.getElementById(id),
    row = document.createElement("tr"),
    cellCounter = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;

  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
  checkbox.className = 'checkbox_done';
  checkbox.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteRow(event)');

  var btnEdit = document.createElement("input");
  btnEdit.type = 'image';
  btnEdit.className = 'btnEdit';
  btnEdit.src = 'icons/edit.png';
  btnEdit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    editButton();
    return false;
  });

  var btnDelete = document.createElement("input");
  btnDelete.type = 'image';
  btnDelete.className = 'btnDelete';
  btnDelete.src = 'icons/delete.png';
  btnDelete.setAttribute('onclick', 'delButton(event)');

  var tdNum = document.createElement("td");
  tdNum.setAttribute("id", "td1_id");
  tdNum.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellCounter));

  var tdDone = document.createElement("td");
  tdDone.appendChild(checkbox);

  var tdItem = document.createElement("td");
  tdItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("add_id").value));

  var tdQuant = document.createElement("td");
  tdQuant.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("quant_id").value));

  var tdPrice = document.createElement("td");
  tdPrice.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("price_id").value));

  var tdAction = document.createElement("td");
  tdAction.setAttribute('colspan', '2');
  tdAction.appendChild(btnEdit);
  tdAction.appendChild(btnDelete);

  row.appendChild(tdNum);
  row.appendChild(tdDone);
  row.appendChild(tdItem);
  row.appendChild(tdQuant);
  row.appendChild(tdPrice);
  row.appendChild(tdAction);

  tbody.appendChild(row);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Cart - Shopping List</title>
</head>

<body class="body">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="li_index"><a class="link_index" href="index.html">Shopping list</a></li>
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="done.html">Done</a></li>
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="deleted.html">Deleted</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <h1 class="h1">Shopping List</h1>
    <hr class="hr">
    <div class="inputs">
      <input class="input_add" type="text" id="add_id" placeholder="Add items to you Shopping List">
      <input class="input_quant" type="text" id="quant_id" placeholder="Quant.">
      <input class="input_price" type="text" id="price_id" placeholder="Price">
      <button class="input_button" type="button" onclick="insertRow('myTable');return false;">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="table">
    <table class="mytable" id="myTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
      <tbody id="tbody">
        <tr id="tr_id" class="tr">
          <td>#</td>
          <td>Done</td>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>Quantity</td>
          <td>Price $</td>
          <td colspan="2" width="100">Action</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: подход неправильный. нужно по нажатии `Add` не добавлять строки в таблицу и из инпутов добавлять ячейкам значения, а надо заносить данные в массив/объект, и уже на основе массива/объекта строить таблицу. Тогда и `Итого` можно будет добавить основываясь банально на `array.length` ........отправить данные на сервер тоже будет явно проще

Comment: К сожалению, подход хоть и не правильный, но пока приходится работать с тем, что имеем... И реализовать "итого" по сумме нужно именно исходя из имеющейся реализации. Если оставить все так "рукожопно" как есть? Что в таком случае нужно делать чтобы получить результат?

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

В таблицу **`class="table"`**, в конец, руками добавляем строку **`id="sum-row"`** в которой есть столбец **`id="show-sum"`**. А при каждом сабмите вставляем новую строку перед строкой **`id="sum-row"`** с помощью [**`insertBefore`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) (столбцу Price назначаем общий класс **`price`**), суммируем **`class="price"`**, вставляем в столбец **`id="show-sum"`**.

```js
function insertRow(id) {
  var tbody = document.getElementById(id),
    row = document.createElement("tr"),
    cellCounter = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;

  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
  checkbox.className = 'checkbox_done';
  checkbox.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteRow(event)');

  var btnEdit = document.createElement("input");
  btnEdit.type = 'image';
  btnEdit.className = 'btnEdit';
  btnEdit.src = 'icons/edit.png';
  btnEdit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    editButton();
    return false;
  });

  var btnDelete = document.createElement("input");
  btnDelete.type = 'image';
  btnDelete.className = 'btnDelete';
  btnDelete.src = 'icons/delete.png';
  btnDelete.setAttribute('onclick', 'delButton(event)');

  var tdNum = document.createElement("td");
  tdNum.setAttribute("id", "td1_id");
  tdNum.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellCounter));

  var tdDone = document.createElement("td");
  tdDone.appendChild(checkbox);

  var tdItem = document.createElement("td");
  tdItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("add_id").value));

  var tdQuant = document.createElement("td");
  tdQuant.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("quant_id").value));

  var tdPrice = document.createElement("td");
  tdPrice.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("price_id").value));
  // столбцу добавляем класс, по которому будем выбирать суммы
  tdPrice.classList += "price";

  var tdAction = document.createElement("td");
  tdAction.setAttribute('colspan', '2');
  tdAction.appendChild(btnEdit);
  tdAction.appendChild(btnDelete);

  row.appendChild(tdNum);
  row.appendChild(tdDone);
  row.appendChild(tdItem);
  row.appendChild(tdQuant);
  row.appendChild(tdPrice);
  row.appendChild(tdAction);

  //-----------------------  
  var sumRow = document.getElementById('sum-row');
  var parentE = sumRow.parentNode;
  parentE.insertBefore(row, sumRow);
  //-----------------------
  var prices = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
  var sum = 0;
  for (i = 0, j = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
    sum += Number(prices[i].innerText);
  }
  document.getElementById('show-sum').innerHTML = sum;
  //-----------------------
}
```

```css
#sum-row{border-color:transparent}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Cart - Shopping List</title>
</head>

<body class="body">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="li_index"><a class="link_index" href="index.html">Shopping list</a></li>
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="done.html">Done</a></li>
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="deleted.html">Deleted</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <h1 class="h1">Shopping List</h1>
    <hr class="hr">
    <div class="inputs">
      <input class="input_add" type="text" id="add_id" placeholder="Add items to you Shopping List">
      <input class="input_quant" type="text" id="quant_id" placeholder="Quant.">
      <input class="input_price" type="text" id="price_id" placeholder="Price">
      <button class="input_button" type="button" onclick="insertRow('myTable');return false;">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="table">
    <table class="mytable" id="myTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
      <tbody id="tbody">
        <tr id="tr_id" class="tr">
          <td>#</td>
          <td>Done</td>
          <td>Item</td>
          <td>Quantity</td>
          <td>Price $</td>
          <td colspan="2" width="100">Action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="sum-row" class="tr">
          <td colspan="4"></td>
          <td id="show-sum"></td>
          <td colspan="2" width="100"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="show-sum" style="text-align:right"></div>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```